# Why two window appears in VisionOS app? I would expect one with two tabbar

Tags: swiftui, visionos

I make this code:

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  VisionOS
//
//  Created by János Kukoda on 2023. 08. 01..
//

import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showImmersiveSpace = false

    @Environment(\.openImmersiveSpace) var openImmersiveSpace
    @Environment(\.dismissImmersiveSpace) var dismissImmersiveSpace

    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
            NavigationSplitView {
                List {
                    Text("Item")
                }
                .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
            } detail: {
                VStack {
                    Model3D(named: "Scene", bundle: realityKitContentBundle)
                        .padding(.bottom, 50)

                    Text("Hello, world!")

                    Toggle("Show ImmersiveSpace", isOn: $showImmersiveSpace)
                        .toggleStyle(.button)
                        .padding(.top, 50)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Content")
                .padding()
            }
            .onChange(of: showImmersiveSpace) { _, newValue in
                Task {
                    if newValue {
                        await openImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace")
                    } else {
                        await dismissImmersiveSpace()
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
            List {
                Text("Item")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have to select "No" - Enable Multiple Windows in info.plist
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPNbb.png)